# So maybe I'm not getting the idea in Ruby but I have a question about Enumerables inject

Tags: ruby, irb, enumerable, inject, operator-precedence

The |m,k| thing kind of throws me off. Does this have anything to do with order of precedence?
m standing for 0 (or 1 in some languages) and k for the last in the Array/Hash whatever?

So why do people put a number in .inject()?

Alternatively, is there an easy way to learn how to use this, and exactly what it's value is? Judging from this question I hope you all know I'm pretty noobish to any programming language and Ruby was my first choice.

Comment: Do you have a particular example you'd like explaining? kjfletch's answer is good bt if you expand your question a bit people might be able to provide more details.

Answer (score 6):

Let's try an example.

```
numbers = [ 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9 ]
sum = numbers.inject(0) do |prefix_sum, number|
  prefix_sum + number
end
```

`#inject` takes one argument and a block.  The block should take two values, and return a new value.

In the above example, the argument to `#inject` is `0`, and the block is `do |prefix_sum, number| prefix_sum + number end`.  The values that will be passed to the block are named in between the two `|` markers: `prefix_sum` and `number`.

Each value of the enumerable `#inject` was called on is passed as the second value to the block in turn. In this example `number` will be `3`, then `1`, then `4`, then `1`, then `5`, then finally `9`.  So in this example, the block will be invoked six times; once for each position in `numbers`.

The first value passed to a block (here named `prefix_sum`) is usually called an *accumulator*.  Its initial value, the value used the first time the block is called by `#inject`, is set by the argument passed to `#inject` (in this example, `0`).  The return value of the block determines the value of the accumulator (`prefix_sum`) for the next invocation of the block.

When there are no more elements to process, the value of the accumulator is returned (and here stored in `sum`).

So lets walk through it:

- `#inject` receives `0` and our block.
- `#inject` invokes our block, binding `prefix_sum` to `0` (the initial accumulator value) and `number` to `3` (the first array value).
- our block calculates `0+3` as `3` and returns it.
- `#inject` invokes our block, binding `prefix_sum` to `3` (the returned value) and `number` to `1` (the second array value)
- our block calculates `3+1` as `4` and returns it.
- `#inject` invokes our block, binding `prefix_sum` to `4` (the returned value) and `number` to `4` (the third array value)
- our block calculates `4+4` as `8` and returns it.
- `#inject` invokes our block, binding `prefix_sum` to `8` (the returned value) and `number` to `1` (the fourth array value)
- our block calculates `8+1` as `9` and returns it.
- `#inject` invokes our block, binding `prefix_sum` to `9` (the returned value) and `number` to `5` (the fifth array value)
- our block calculates `9+5` as `14` and returns it.
- `#inject` invokes our block, binding `prefix_sum` to `14` (the returned value) and `number` to `9` (the sixth array value)
- our block calculates `14+9` as `23` and returns it.
- since there are no more array elements, `#inject` returns `23`, and we bind `sum` to be that value.

You can look at inject as parenthesizing an operation on a list of items, in this example, caluculating:

```
((((((0 + 3) + 1) + 4) + 1) + 5) + 9)
```

This lets you take any operation which normally only operates on a pair of arguments, and apply it to a list.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be confusing block arguments with method arguments.

The number people pass into the inject() method is a method argument that determines the initial value for "m" when you use |m,k| for the block. I don't know where you saw them named m and k, or why they were named so, but it's certainly not because they stand for the first and last element.

It would be simpler to look at it in the way described in kjfletch's link, [breakdown of an inject()](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html), where they're named "result" and "element" instead.

The value in using inject() is the ability to be concise. Anything you want to do with inject() could also be done with a call to the each() method, with a much longer block, and extra variable declarations. See [this question and the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169099/how-do-you-concisely-get-the-average-house-price-from-an-array-of-houses) to get a feeling for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out what any method does in Ruby, you can use the bundled `ri` tool (so you could type "ri Enumerable.inject" to look up the docs) or search [Ruby-Doc](http://ruby-doc.org). In this case, you would [see](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003140):

> Combines the elements of enum by applying the block to an accumulator value (memo) and each element in turn. At each step, memo is set to the value returned by the block. The first form lets you supply an initial value for memo. The second form uses the first element of the collection as a the initial value (and skips that element while iterating).

```
# Sum some numbers
(5..10).inject {|sum, n| sum + n }              #=> 45
# Multiply some numbers
(5..10).inject(1) {|product, n| product * n }   #=> 151200

# find the longest word
longest = %w{ cat sheep bear }.inject do |memo,word|
  memo.length > word.length ? memo : word
end
longest                                         #=> "sheep"

# find the length of the longest word
longest = %w{ cat sheep bear }.inject(0) do |memo,word|
  memo >= word.length ? memo : word.length
end
longest                                         #=> 5
```

Answer (score 1):

The |x,y| are used when using blocks. When the yield statement is called you tell it to map the calling variables to x and y.

Look here [Blocks and Yield](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm)

See here for a [breakdown of an inject()](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html) call.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: *m* usually means *memo*; *k* may mean *key* (often uses in conjunction with *v*, which means *value*). So, for example:

```
stuff.inject({}) { |m,(k,v)| m.merge(k.to_sym => v) }
```

I've also seen people use *a* for *accumulator* and *e* for element, like this:

```
numbers.inject { |a,e| a+e }
```